# Can we show Hub Site Navigation on classic pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hub-site, classic-experience

I have a modern communication site collection which is defined as a Hub Site. and a classic team site which is connected to the Hubsite. now inside the classic site if i use the modern UI the Hub site navigation will be shown which is fine, but if i have a classic page then the Hub site navigation will disappears.. so is there a way to enable the Hub site navigation on classic page?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Hub navigation is not supported in classic experience, and I do not find any related update in plan either.

Here is a UserVoice post you can vote for if you have similar request: [Enable Hub Site Navigation on Classic PAges.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/35242636-enable-hub-site-navigation-on-classic-pages)